# Creating Date range on the base of fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having following table as input

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp11
(
    Field1              INT,
    Date1               DATETIME,
    Status1             VARCHAR(50),
    Status2             VARCHAR(50),
    Status3             VARCHAR(50),
    Status4             VARCHAR(50),
    ConcatStatus        VARCHAR(1000)
)


INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-05' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-06' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-07' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');

INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-11' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-12' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-13' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');

INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-17' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-18' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-19' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
```

Now , i want following Output

```
FromDate    |ToDate     |Status1    |Status2    |Status3    |Status4
====================================================================
05-Jan      |07-Jan     |Yes        |Yes        |Yes        |Yes
08-Jan      |10-Jan     |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |NULL
11-Jan      |11-Jan     |No         |No         |No         |No
12-Jan      |12-Jan     |Yes        |Yes        |Yes        |Yes
13-Jan      |13-Jan     |No         |No         |No         |No
14-Jan      |16-Jan     |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |NULL
17-Jan      |19-Jan     |No         |No         |No         |No
```

Logic here is ,
If all the status are same the Date1 filed should be converted to Date Rage 
and missing date range should have null values

For Example, the records of 5-Jan , 6-Jan , 7-Jan all have same value in all fours status filed they have been combined and given a date range of 5-Jan to 7-Jan.

I tried to concatenate all the status and then try to apply partition and over by but it is not working.

Comment: Is there ever a scenario that one of the Status on a single day could be different? In your example all the statuses are the same on a given day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be shortened/optimized, but here's a solution.  Only problem is that you are probably going to have to mess with MAXRECURSION if there's a lot of data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp11;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Temp11
(
    Field1              INT,
    Date1               DATE,
    Status1             VARCHAR(50),
    Status2             VARCHAR(50),
    Status3             VARCHAR(50),
    Status4             VARCHAR(50),
    ConcatStatus        VARCHAR(1000)
)


INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-05' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-06' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-07' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');

INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-11' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-12' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes' , 'Yes','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-13' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');

INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-17' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-18' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
INSERT INTO #Temp11 VALUES(111 , '2018-01-19' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No' , 'No','');
GO

SELECT * FROM #Temp11;
GO

WITH
    ordered AS (
        SELECT  Field1 ,
                Date1 ,
                Status1 ,
                Status2 ,
                Status3 ,
                Status4 ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY Date1) AS RowNumber
        FROM    #Temp11
    ) ,
    combined AS (
        SELECT  Field1 ,
                Date1 ,
                CAST(NULL AS Date) AS Date2 ,
                Status1 ,
                Status2 ,
                Status3 ,
                Status4 ,
                RowNumber
        FROM    ordered
        WHERE   RowNumber = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  o.Field1 ,
                CASE WHEN o.Status1 = c.Status1 AND o.Status2 = c.Status2 AND o.Status3 = c.Status3 AND o.Status4 = c.Status4
                    THEN c.Date1 ELSE o.Date1 END ,
                CASE WHEN o.Status1 = c.Status1 AND o.Status2 = c.Status2 AND o.Status3 = c.Status3 AND o.Status4 = c.Status4
                    THEN o.Date1 ELSE NULL END ,
                o.Status1 ,
                o.Status2 ,
                o.Status3 ,
                o.Status4 ,
                o.RowNumber
        FROM    ordered o
        INNER JOIN combined c
                ON c.Field1 = o.Field1
                AND c.RowNumber = o.RowNumber - 1
    ) ,
    results AS (
        SELECT  Field1 ,
                Date1 ,
                Date2 ,
                Status1 ,
                Status2 ,
                Status3 ,
                Status4 ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1, Date1 ORDER BY Date2 DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM    combined
    )
SELECT  Field1 ,
        Date1 ,
        Date2 ,
        Status1,
        Status2,
        Status3,
        Status4
FROM    results
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY Field1 ,
        Date1
```